# Should URLs in JSON data be encoded?

Tags: json

Is it standard practice to return URLs in JSON data (e.g. from an API) in a percent-encoded format, or to leave them unencoded?

```
{
    "url": "http:\/\/www.mydomain.com\/some%20path"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple and short answer: Until there is no specific need to encode them, you should not do it.

So, best practice is to leave them unencoded.